# How do I reset to default drop down list option on refresh(F5) in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a ddl in firefox that does not get reset to the default caption. How do I do this?
This is what I have so far.

```
<%string ddlVal = ""%>
<select id="detailSelect" name="DetailSelect">
    <option <%if (ddlVal == "") { Response.Write("selected = &quot;selected&quot;"); } %> value="" >--Choose One--</option>
    <option <%if (ddlVal == "Building") { Response.Write("selected = &quot;selected&quot;"); } %> value="Building">Building</option>
    <option <%if (ddlVal == "Contents") { Response.Write("selected = &quot;selected&quot;"); } %> value="Contents">Contents</option>
</select>
```

On a refresh, the ddl is the what is being displayed before the refresh, and not the default ddl.  How do I corect this?

Comment: On a completely unrelated basis: is this the how you usually generate drop down lists in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: That drop down list code is terrifying...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

add `autocomplete="off"` to the `<select>` tag. This is a known issue in firefox remembering your dropdown selection.

Comment: the select or the option tag?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he is referring to the select tag

Comment: It works in FF but not in IE9. Also Netbeans-IDE tells me "autocomplete" in "select" it's not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution.
First Write jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#originCountry').val(0);
});
```

In MVC Razor View

```
@Html.DropDownList("originCountry", new SelectList(ViewBag.countriesList, "CountryId", "CountryName"), "Please select country", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "javascript:GetOriginCities(this.value);", @required = "required" })
```